# Moved library to a different folder, now the program doesn't work

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

So here's what happenned:

- I made a project in NetBeans and wanted to use a function from Apache library.
- Downloaded the library, hooked it up to NetBeans, used function, it worked.
- The unpacked zip file of the library was on the desktop, didn't like it there. Created a folder in Documents, named it "Library", moved the apache library there.
- Project Problem occurred: "Common-lang3 library has missing items".
- Tried resolving the problem by clicking "Add JAR/Folder" and finding it manually. Didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the library where it was (to desktop) then in NetBeans remove library from a project -> move library to new destination -> add it back to the project (from new destination).

Also, when you are executing your compiled app, you must have in the same location as the JAR file folder `lib` with all required libraries inside, including already mentioned library `Common-lang3` (NetBeans should move it there automatically on build).

Comment: I tried.It created one more mistake "Contains file with errors." But I don't get it, I didn't change anything within the files, just the folder where the library was.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look to `maven`. Maven is a software project management tool for Java.

You can get informations about maven from here:

[apache maven startsite](https://maven.apache.org/)

[how to install maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

After you have configured maven on your system and created a java project based on maven you can add all your dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. Which is the configuration file for maven.

The commom-lang3 library is simply a dependency in your project and will be downloaded automatically. This is how you add a dependency to a pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But first, you should look at maven installation and the use of it. It will make your life easier by handling all the necessary dependencies you need in this project and in all of your other projects in future.

Comment: @pompoen your welcome, its more or less a standard in java development. I really recommend to use it